# Ways to change id attribute in html

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm building a website and I have an unsorted list with some list elements. When I click on some of these list items I want my `<body>`’s id to change from `id="index"` to `id="collection"`.

What's the most efficient way to do that?

1. Should I use JavaScript?
2. Should I put all the body code in a `{% block %}` and override it when I click on the special list items?
3. An other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a purely JavaScript persepctive, the simplest and best way of changing the body's ID is

```
document.body.id = "collection";
```

However, you may be better off using a class to avoid any potential conflict of your ID with any other ID in the page. Giving the body an ID doesn't seem terribly useful given that there is only one `<body>` element in the page and it can be referenced via `document.body` in JavaScript and `body` in CSS.

If you want to change an element in the page without reloading the whole page then JavaScript is your only option. If the change is vital to the functionality of your page, you should also provide a non-JavaScript fallback.

Comment: +1 - not sure who down voted but it seemed harsh. I also agree that giving the body an ID is rarely useful.

Comment: Agree with Tim, changing the id seems wrong, you shouldn't need to change ids. Changing a class seems more like what you want in this case, specially if you're using it so that different CSS will apply

Answer (score 1):

> **Should I use JavaScript?**

Yes, based on the knowledge that you want this to happen during a click event.  The most efficient way would be

```
document.body.id = "collection";
```

a less efficient way would be

```
document.getElementById("index").id = "collection";
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by “efficient”. Using JavaScript means the `id` gets changed without another HTTP request being made to your server, so the user doesn’t have to wait for the page to reload.

However, if they revisit or reload the page after clicking on one of these list items, the list will go back to the way it was when the page was loaded. That might not be optimal for your context.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using jQuery, with the line `$('#index').attr('id', 'collection');`.

Comment: Question wasn't asked with the jQuery tag nor did the asker mention jQuery at all. THis is much easier to understand and implement without using jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is a subset of Javascript.  The question is already schizophrenic, since it asks how to change the id "in HTML" and then is tagged with, and mentions Javascript.

Comment: if we’re splitting hairs, jQuery is a *framework written in* JavaScript, rather than a *subset of* JavaScript. Calling it a subset implies that there are parts of JavaScript that you can’t use when you’re writing jQuery, and I don’t think that’s true.

Comment: Surely it is equally nonsensical to call jQuery out-of-bounds when Javascript is in-bounds.

Comment: that implies that using jQuery requires nothing in the term of learning a new library and syntax which isn't the case. Just because somebody knows JavaScript does not mean they can simply switch to jQuery on a whim.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById( "index" ).id = "collection";
```