# How to reset an html id

Tags: javascript

I have a id on a `<button>` in javascript, i change the id from '1' to '2'. since it's a button, it's set on a add to shopping cart button in a modal. Going from id '1' to '2', i wanna reset the '2' so i can work with '1' again. I tried everything i can, but still can't manage to solve the problem. Can you guys help me out? thanks.

```
<div class="card-body">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" onClick="reset();" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" onClick="add_price(this); add_image(this); " id="1" class="addtocart btn-primary">Add to cart <i class="fas fa-cart-plus ml-2" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use an ID to track this, IDs are for DOM related manipulations. Instead, use a `data-*` attribute to track it, or a variable elsewhere

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784843/ways-to-change-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: Plus, remember to point out what you have tried and which error you are getting. Tested here and just setting the `id` works fine.

Comment: Why do you need to modify it from '1' to '2' ?
And what is the purpose to use '1' again ??

Comment: @SterlingArcher hey, then how do i call it from javascript? for example, document.getElementById, i use that to call the id. How do i call a data- attribute?

Comment: @balduran I got a modal. Got an id for "add to cart" button. by adding the items to the shopping cart, i change the id from for example '1' to '2' to change the image when it's' added to the cart. now i am stuck on the id number '2', so whenever i click on "add to cart", it keeps showing the same image and not the first picture

Comment: If you add a `data-id="whatever"` to the button, you would access it like this: `document.getElementById('1').dataset.id` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset

Comment: In this case, use data to store 'the number of items in cart'. for the images, use class.