# changing a value of id in html, then changing it back

Tags: javascript, html

i know that this is a messy code, but i really need help with this problem that i yet can't solve. so for my project i am building a E-shop. i got modals for my products, and i got a button within the modal for adding the item to the cart. On the button i got an id="1"; and in the javascript as you can see i am changing it from "1" to "2". and i **succeeded** with that. and now i am stuck in id="2", so i want to reset the value of the id. But i don't know how.

```
function changeImage(button) {
 var exchangeimage = button.id;
 if (exchangeimage == 'modalopen1') {
   var image = document.getElementById('pic1');
   if (image.src.match("https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/E- 
       commerce/Vertical/img%20(24).jpg")) {
         image.src = "https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/E- 
          commerce/Vertical/img%20(23).jpg";
        } else {
          image.src = "https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/E- 
          commerce/Vertical/img%20(24).jpg";
        }
    }

 if (exchangeimage == 'modalopen2') {
    var image2 = document.getElementById('pic1');
    document.getElementById('1').id='2';
  }
 if (image2.src.match("https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/E-            
    commerce/Vertical/img%20(26).jpg")) {
    image2.src = "https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/E- 
    commerce/Vertical/img%20(23).jpg";
  } else {
     image2.src = "https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/E- 
     commerce/Vertical/img%20(26).jpg";
  }


}


 function add_image(button) {
   var image = button.id;
      if (image == '1') {
        show_image("http://bestjquery.com/tutorial/product-grid/demo11                        /images/img-1.jpg", 155, 206, "image");   
  }

 if (image == '2') {
     show_image("http://bestjquery.com/tutorial/product-grid/demo11/images/img-3.jpg", 155, 206, 
 "image");
  }


}
```

Comment: How is this question different to [this one from an hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658389/how-to-reset-an-html-id)?

Comment: it's not, i wanted to be more specific.

Comment: Then edit your question instead of asking a new one

Answer (score 0):

just get the element again now with id=2 and set the id back to 1

```js
document.getElementById('1').id='2';

document.getElementById('2').id='1';
```

```html
<div id='1'></div>
```

Comment: hello, yes i tried that. Then when i clicked on the "add to cart" button. it went straight from '2' to '1'. but if i want to add more items, it needs to stay on '2', before i wanna do '1'.

Comment: what i meant was, when i close the modal, that is when i want to change the value from '2' to '1'.

Comment: place the second line document.getElementById('2').id='1'   at the beginning or end of your add to cart function

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery/bootstrap then you could change it back when the modal closes.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#modalopen2').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
  $("#2").attr({"id":"1"})
  });
});
</script>
```

I could provide a better answer if I knew when you wanted the value to change back.

Comment: Hi, yes, that is what i want, when the modal closes, i want the id value to return to '1'. because when i am in '2', if i want to add more items, i want to stay in '2'. then when i am done, i close the modal, then i want it go back to '1'. So i am using javascript, not jquery.